# Unity Admob Showing Mix of Test and Real ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am working in Unity 2020.3.13 using the Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.0.1 package running banners, interstitials, and rewarded ads. My Admob account is in fine standing and has other apps showing real ads without issue, and none of the Admob Ids described below were recently created.
In the Unity editor everything shows as a test ad even though I have set the real app ID and Ad Unit IDs from Admob.  The problem is that once the app builds in Xcode the banner ads show as real ads, while the rewarded ads show as test ads still.  I have double and triple checked the Ad Unit IDs they are all correct.  Any ideas why I am seeing real ads for banners but test ads for Rewarded?

Answer (score 0):

Some where in your code you've added your device as a test device or you are testing using emulator.

To verify this use another phone that you did not use before.

Comment: Jabbar, I have not added a test device.  I have only used the bare minimum code associated with the Admob rewarded ad documentation.  I know the problem is not my code itself because roughly the same code works fine in apps that are currently published.  This project has some unity files that were copied from a different one -- I think that may be what is throwing it off.  Have you ever heard of something like that happening?

Comment: @PaulTucker test Ads are device specific, so they will appear on testing devices only (could be emulators), did you tried testing it on completely new device?